# JavaFX Filechooser: Save Image to Resources and save Path to Database

Tags: java, javafx

i want to save a selected image which i get with the FileChooser into my Resource folder within the existing project. After this, i want to save the path into my database.

I use JavaFX for this and put the whole code within the "Submit Button" action. Now the code takes the path of the selected image and creates a new image. How can i save this image now to my directory and how do i get the path to this?

```
@FXML
public void pathButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    LOG.info("Image Path button clicked");

    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser.setTitle("Select Image File");

    chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files",
            "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg"));

    File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

if(file != null){
        LOG.info("Got file " + file);
       // String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();

            try {
                String imagePath = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
                Image image = new Image(imagePath, 500,500,true,true,true);
                LOG.info("Image created " + image);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{
        LOG.info("File not found!");
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText("Please Select a File");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
```

Comment: You can't save to the `resources` folder: that folder is part of the source code structure, and the source code is not generally available at runtime. Typically the contents of the resources are deployed to the root of the class path, and then that is bundled into a jar file. You can't write into the jar file of a bundled application.

Comment: hi, ok interessting. can you send me a snippet or a link how i can do this?